# How to restore date like "2008-7" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, types

I decleared the column as "datetime",which failed to restore value like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2008-7` isn't a date. `2008-7-1` is a date (the first of July). If you want to store values like `2008-7`, you'll want a character field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to clean up the data?

1. make it a `varchar`
2. `update t set d = concat(d, '-1')`
3. change it to a `date` type